# Error installing ruby on macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

Tags: ruby, rvm

I've just moved to a new machine, and used the Migration Assistant to move everything over. I'm having some problems installing Ruby 2.5.1 using rvm.

I run this command: `rvm install 2.5.1 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/bin/openssl` (note: I've tried it without the openssl stuff, I've put ruby-2.5.1, but the same error comes up; I'm installed the Xcode command line tools and accepted the licence agreement).

I get this:

```
ruby-2.5.1 - #removing src/ruby-2.5.1..
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem' is already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/tims/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.5.1 - #downloading ruby-2.5.1, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.5.1 - #extracting ruby-2.5.1 to /Users/tims/.rvm/src/ruby-2.5.1....
ruby-2.5.1 - #configuring...................................................................
ruby-2.5.1 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.5.1 - #compiling........
Error running '__rvm_make -j 1',
please read /Users/tims/.rvm/log/1526070632_ruby-2.5.1/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

The make.log is this:

```
[2018-05-11 16:31:32] __rvm_make
__rvm_make () 
{ 
    \make "$@" || return $?
}
current path: /Users/tims/.rvm/src/ruby-2.5.1
GEM_HOME=/Users/tims/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2
PATH=/usr/local/opt/coreutils/bin:/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/Users/tims/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin:/Users/tims/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/bin:/Users/tims/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin:/Users/tims/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin:/Users/tims/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global/bin:/Users/tims/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin:/Users/tims/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
GEM_PATH=/Users/tims/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2:/Users/tims/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global
command(3): __rvm_make -j 1
++ make -j 1
    CC = gcc
    LD = ld
    LDSHARED = gcc -dynamiclib
    CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens   -fno-common -pipe 
    XCFLAGS = -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
    CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin17 -I./include -I. -I./enc/unicode/10.0.0
    DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -install_name /Users/tims/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/libruby.2.5.dylib -compatibility_version 2.5 -current_version 2.5.1  -fstack-protector -framework Foundation  -fstack-protector -framework Foundation  
    SOLIBS = -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lobjc 
    LANG = en_CA.UTF-8
    LC_ALL = 
    LC_CTYPE = 
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
compiling ./main.c
compiling dmydln.c
compiling miniinit.c
compiling dmyext.c
compiling miniprelude.c
translating probes probes.d
. ./vm_opts.h
compiling array.c
compiling bignum.c
compiling class.c
compiling compar.c
compiling compile.c
compiling complex.c
compiling cont.c
compiling debug.c
compiling debug_counter.c
compiling dir.c
compiling dln_find.c
compiling encoding.c
compiling enum.c
compiling enumerator.c
compiling error.c
compiling eval.c
compiling file.c
In file included from file.c:23:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFString.h:13:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:72:
/usr/local/include/Block.h:62:3: error: unknown type name 'CloogState'
  CloogState *state;            /**< State. */
  ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:63:3: error: unknown type name 'CloogStatement'
  CloogStatement * statement ;  /**< The list of statements in the block. */
  ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:65:3: error: unknown type name 'cloog_int_t'
  cloog_int_t *scaldims;        /**< Scalar dimension values. */
  ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:90:34: error: unknown type name 'FILE'
void cloog_block_print_structure(FILE *, CloogBlock *, int) ;
                                 ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:91:24: error: unknown type name 'FILE'
void cloog_block_print(FILE *, CloogBlock *) ;
                       ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:92:29: error: unknown type name 'FILE'
void cloog_block_list_print(FILE *, CloogBlockList *) ;
                            ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:105:37: error: unknown type name 'CloogState'
CloogBlock     * cloog_block_malloc(CloogState *state);
                                    ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:106:36: error: unknown type name 'CloogStatement'
CloogBlock     * cloog_block_alloc(CloogStatement *statement, int nb_scaldims,
                                   ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:107:9: error: unknown type name 'cloog_int_t'
                                    cloog_int_t *scaldims, int depth);
                                    ^
9 errors generated.
make: *** [file.o] Error 1
++ return 2
```

Any help would be appreciated.

ETA: Things I've tried without success:

- Thinking this might be related to rvm, I moved over to rbenv to give it another try, and the same error arises.
- I've used homebrew to reinstall pkg-config, isl, gmp and cloog.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/22359

Comment: Good find, but it didn't help. :(

Comment: Are you able to install older versions of ruby?

Comment: Mmmmmm would installing cloog via homebrew conflict with ruby build? I have never needed to install cloog explictly imho.

Comment: Ive tried 2.5.0 and 2.4 without success. I’ve never needed to install cloog separately, either. It’s super weird.

Comment: Ultimately, I reformatted and reinstalled macOS, and things are now installing fine. Not a very satisfactory solution to this problem, but I was at the end of my tether.